# What is the default coordinate of GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I am using Google Maps iOS SDK.
I have installed the pod 'GoogleMaps'.
I have done the instantiation of Google Maps Services with Google API Key in App delegate.
I have created a UIView in storyboard and changed the view's class to GMSMapView and created outlet as mapView.
In viewDidLoad(), if i print mapview's coordinate as below, i get the lat long **51.1789, -1.8264**
[image]

Can any one let me know if (51.1789, -1.8264) is the default coordinate of GMSMapView

Comment: If you display those coordinates, they appear to be of Stonehenge. That does not seem accidental. As to whether those are the "default" coordinates of a GMSMapView, I have no idea. Why does it matter? You should always set the map view to a location that is meaningful to your app. You might want to save the last-displayed location to user defaults and display that on launch rather than using the "default" google maps location.